# Is it ok to take a break near the cycle path, on the grass, in Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, bicycles, culture

Today was the first time I cycled in Netherlands. I really enjoyed it. I cycled from Amsterdam to the North Sea and back to Amsterdam.

When I was cycling on the cycle path I became thirsty and tired and I stopped on the right side, on the grass, near the cycle path (at about 20 meters it was a fence and beyond the fence the railway lines).

I drank some water and rested a bit. When I was preparing to leave, while packing my bag back into its place on the back side of the bicycle, there was a young guy with a motor cycle (together with a girl on the same motor cycle, both wearing sun glasses) who yelled something to me in a rude way, but not in English.

He said something which in English would sound like “Heey Looozard!”  I looked at him and he looked at me and made some rude signs with his hands to me.

Now I’m confused why this happened at all.

Have I done something wrong? Is it okay to stop on the grass near the cycle path? Maybe even sit down? What could I have done to avoid this?

Comment: "Hé luiaard !" which is Dutch and roughly translates to 'Hello, lazy bones !" probably comes closest to what you heard. And I presume that Willeke made that assumption as well, judging from her answer. Just another rude loudmouth thinking he is funny.

Comment: @Tonny the word “loser” has been assimilated by the Dutch, so possibly he simply said “hey loser” with a Dutch accent. Additionally, “luiaard” is too mild and old fashioned and/or to be shouted by some idiot on a motor cycle - it’s quite far from “street speak”.

Comment: @11684 Loser isn’t used at all where I am from (Brabant). But in the big city things could be different. I admit I seldom go up north. I’m thinking he actually said “hey losert” which I have heard before, with a thick The Hague accent

Comment: Did you leave the bike on the bike line while you sat down? That is the only thing I can imagine you would have done 'wrong'. Even yelling 'hey loser' or something similar sounds very vague to me (you see so many people stopping/resting on benches near a bicycle lane) so I doubt he was even directing it at you.

Aside from that I wonder why the comment that this person was black was added, it does not seem to add to the story or possible explanation at all.

Comment: @11684: "Luiaard" is a lot less hostile though. It could've been a misplaced attempt at a playful taunt as opposed to actual angry shouting. I considered that they shouted "loser" first, but concede that "luiaard" is likely as well, given that there has been no cause for hostility between them. I don't think you can assume that what was said must invariably be street speak based on OP's description of the situation/guy.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I did take the bike on the grass, at about 2 meters distance from the cycle path; it was definitely not on the line. It was obvious he directed the words at me. I noted he was black just so that you can understand/imagine him (I'm definitely not against black people)—I mentioned he was black, wearing sun glasses etc.

Comment: @Flater In my experience, people who swear at people on the street generally use less formal/proper language. However, it was just a guess; I wasn’t there and can’t know.

Comment: @11684: But that's the point. "Luiaard" wouldn't really be swearing if it was meant jokingly (not angrily), hence why it fits with the described situation where there was no reason for anger.

Comment: @Flater If someone I didn’t know called me a “luiaard” on the streets I would be offended. As a joke I would call it very ill advised. However, the OP described the shouter making “rude signs with his hands”, so I don’t think it was very friendly.

Comment: a rude american tourist maybe?

Comment: @jean The accent was definitely not American.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was just a random idiot. They think they are tough and do it as a kind of macho behavior. Some people just like to bully people or call out people like that. And I also think he actually said "hey loser".

Comment: As a human, I can confirm random idiots can show up everywhere. As a Dutchman, I can confirm that they can show up in The Netherlands as well.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Likely that a not funny guy tried to be funny, saying something like 'Lazy bones' not knowing or not caring you would not understand. Ignore the kind of guy wherever you go.

Unless the grass is clearly private property, or clearly grown for hay, you are alright taking a rest in it.
Such a small strip between a cycle path and the railway fence is very unlikely to be private.

If it is not clear it is public property and you do not want to damage hay while growing you can wait till you find a bench or other bit that is clearly meant to have a rest.
In the Netherlands you will find quite a few 'rest' places along the bike lanes. But in nice weather using the grass is very nice. I have used it often while cycling.
(I live in the Netherlands and I have done so all my life and I cycle often.)